# Google Sheet Formula: How to convert a string to Bool value?

Tags: arrays, boolean, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

In Google Sheet strings are deemed as False while numbers True.

> =OR(FALSE,A1)

If A1 is a number other than 0, then it returns TRUE; if it is a string, then it returns False.

My real case is that I am using VLOOKUP to check if payer_info(email and phone) exists in our database

```
=OR(
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(payer_phone,'student_list'!C:C,1,false),false), 
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(payer_email,'student_list'!D:D,1,false),false)
)
```

I expect the above formula to return TRUE if `payer_email` exists in `'student_list'!D:D` or `payer_phone` exists in `'student_list'!C:C`. However, `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(payer_email,'student_list'!D:D,1,false),false)` will be deemed as FALSE in the `OR` function because it returns the email string.

So, is there any formula I can use to convert a not empty string to TRUE?

```
what_function(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(payer_email,'student_list'!D:D,1,false),false))
```

If VLOOKUP does find the value then it should return TRUE, if not it returns FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=((IFERROR(VLOOKUP(payer_phone, 'student_list'!C:C, 1, 0))="")+ 
  (IFERROR(VLOOKUP(payer_email, 'student_list'!D:D, 1, 0))=""))=0
```

Comment: `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(payer_email, 'student_list'!D:D, 1, 0), FALSE)` returns an email string and it can't be a parameter of ADD. according to the error message I get from my sheet.

Comment: @shenkwen can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the length of what's returned:

```
=OR(LEN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(payer_phone,'student_list'!C:C,1,false)), 
LEN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(payer_email,'student_list'!D:D,1,false))
)
```

Comment: is this a new question? or an answer? if the latter please edit it into shape to look like an answer and not a new question